# CPP error C2440 cannot convert from HANDLE to HINSTANCE

Tags: c++

Trying to compile a piece of code from an open-source site to help me with an issue I have, however what is supposed to be a working piece of code is giving me the following error ;

Error C2440  "="  cannot convert from HANDLE to HINSTANCE
conversion from *void to pointer to non-void requires explicit cast

```
HINSTANCE Inst;

// ***PROTOTYPES***

void    _stdcall noname_sub001(HWND MsgTargetAddress);
void    _stdcall noname_sub002();
LRESULT _stdcall noname_sub003(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

// ***CODE***

BOOL WINAPI DllMain (HANDLE hInst, ULONG ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    Inst = hInst;
    return 1;
}
```

I cannot work it out despite the old Google search, would appreciate some help please. 
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a pointer to the code in question? What you've included in the question seems to contain a conversion from `HINSTANCE` to `HANDLE`, but the error message you've quoted seems to be talking about converting in the reverse direction.

Comment: The signature of `DllMain` is incorrect, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @RichardCritten I see now, got it, thank you. Also JerryCoffin